# How to group 2 metrics in prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have 2 metrics from 2 micro services. One of them do add(+-1), other do set true absolute value each hour. I need merge 2 metrics. First service(sub-add-service) must add(+-1) to metric from second service(absolute-value-service) and second service must set absolute value. But now I have:

```
item_state_count{service="sub-add-service", state="imported"}
item_state_count{service="absolute-value-service",state="imported"}
```

When we have value from absolute-value-service we set it. :
[Result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckN5P.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can add operands on Grafana, so

```
item_state_count{service="sub-add-service", state="imported"} + item_state_count{service="absolute-value-service",state="imported"}
```

will do it.

Comment: it wont work, as the label values are different.
Putting `sum( ... )` around both operands will probably be enough to fix it

(note that this is not grafana - this is prometheus doing arithmetic)